# In R, use the ls() function with a regular expression to save only character objects?

Tags: r, regex

I have created more than 100 objects that are each two-part character strings.  They all begin the first part with an equal sign, For example,

```
intro <- c("=intro", "For calendar year 2007 blah blah.")

 str(intro)
 chr [1:2] "=intro" ...
```

My goal is to combine all of those objects into a data frame that has the first part, the one preceded by "=" in the first column and the second part, the sentence or sentences, in the second column.

To save all the objects as a data frame:

```
character.objects <- data.frame(chrobjects = ls(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Is there a way to use the pattern = argument of the ls function so that only the chr [1:2] objects are saved in the character.objects data frame?  Or, how else can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Some context would be nice. What language is this?

Comment: How are your objects like `intro` named? Is there any consistency or similar naming scheme?

Comment: No consistency, except they have no punctuation and are all one word.  I have thought about adding "txt" to the start of them, but doing that means more than 220 changes by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, creating a bunch of variables like that is probably not a good design strategy. Most likely those values should be combined into a list or something. But one way to find the names of all such variables is

```
whatIwant<-function(x) {
    z <- get(x)
    if (is.character(z)) {
        if (length(z)==2) {
            if (substr(z[1],1,1)=="=")
                return(TRUE)
        }
    }
    return(FALSE)
}

myvars <- Filter(whatIwant, ls())
```

So `ls()` returns a character vector with the names of all the objects in your workspace. I use `Filter` to reduce that list to only the names we are interested in. I wrote the custom function `whatIwant` to help find those values.

The helper function uses the names from `ls()` and then actually gets the object via `get()`. Then we check the class and length and values to make sure it matches your criteria. So `myvars` should be a character vector with only the names of the variables that match your description

And then we can turn that vector of variable names into a data.frame containing their values with something like

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(myvars), function(x) data.frame(key=x[1], val=x[2])))
```

or maybe

```
myvals <- mget(myvars)
data.frame(key=sapply(myvals, `[`, 1), val=sapply(myvals, `[`, 2))
```

Note this solution does not use the `pattern=` parameter of the `ls()` function because that parameter only works against the name of the objects, not the contents or type of the objects themselves.

Comment: Mr. Flick, I am awed, and timid about commenting because I do not understand the Filter function and that it returns a function, myvars. I ran the do.call and Error in get(myvars) : invalid first argument.  I don't know where to begin to figure it out.

Comment: @user2583119 I've updated by answer to include further details. I would check the value of `myvars` after running the `Filter` step. It should contain all the names of the objects you wish to combine. Does it look reasonable?

Comment: It works perfectly.  I had a some interference from earlier work.  Once I cleared my objects and started over, all was fine.  Now, to learn about get(), Filter() and do.call()!  Thank you

Comment: You can reduce the "workload" slightly by using my `lsclass` function (package `cgwtools`) .  `Filter(whatIwant,lsclass('character')` .

Answer (score 0):

You could also try.

Creating some data

```
intro <- c("=intro", "For calendar year 2007 blah blah.")
intro1 <- c("intro", "For calendar year 2008 blah blah.")
intro2 <- c("intro=", "For calendar year 2009 blah blah.")
intro3 <- c("=intro", "For calendar year 2010 blah")

library(stringr)
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(ls())[sapply(mget(ls()), is.character)], function(x) {
x1 <- x[str_detect(x, perl("(?<=^=)[[:alnum:]]+"))[1]]
if (length(x1) > 0) 
    data.frame(key = x1[1], val = x1[2], stringsAsFactors = F)
}))

res
#         key                               val
#intro  =intro For calendar year 2007 blah blah.
#intro3 =intro       For calendar year 2010 blah
```